# Bash Script to find hardware info giving "Memory Fault"

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, cluster-computing, hardware

I am trying to write a script in work to find out the hardware information in a cluster. I am trying to run the below script, and it is throwing a "Memory Fault" error.
The node.txt file takes in the names of the relevant nodes in the cluster.
Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
function ping()
    {
        ping -c 1 "$host" >> $results
    }
function hw_info_cpu()
    {
        hwinfo --cpu "$host" >> $results
    }
function hw_info_gpu()
    {
        hwinfo --gfxcard "$host" >> $results
    }
function os_info()
    {
        lsb_release -a "$host" >> $results
    }

results=res.txt

while read -r host; do
    ping "$host $results"
    hw_info_cpu "$host $results"
    hw_info_gpu "$host $result"
    os_info "$host $result"
done < nodes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The "ping" function is calling itself recursively.

Rename your "ping" function as "myping"

Comment: Or just use `command ping ...` inside the function to disable function lookup and force the external command to run.